# How to hide Authoring information,Revision information,Publishing options tabs in create/edit node for any content type

Tags: nodes

I am trying to hide Authoring information, Revision information, Publishing options tabs in create/edit node for any content type. I tried different modules with no luck. Please give me suggestions how to achieve this. Thanks a lot[image]

Answer (score 6):

To hide the individual options, you can use the following code in your module_form_alter() function:

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['options']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: thanks the ['options'] one is the one that takes away the publishing tab.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do this with a custom module and drupal's Form API and setting `#access = FALSE` for form elements I want to hide (and test it with 3rd party modules to assure it doesnt break anything).

Recently, I've been made aware of [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) which does exactly this for Drupal 7/6.

Comment: setting access to false worked for me:
in hook_form_alter: `$form['revision_information']['#access'] = false;`

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, Override Node Options can't disable those options, it just can enable them for users that otherwise don't have needed permissions.

There is [Jammer](https://drupal.org/project/jammer) module for removing unneeded elements from display.

Comment: Thanks this makes it easier and more manageable for non developers! Although the "publish" menu cannot be hidden this way? Anyway I like this solution since most users understand "published" but the other options like revision are hard for some end users. And those options can be hidden with the Jammer module :)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code which work for me

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form_id);
  if ( $form_id == 'FORM_ID'){
    $form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false;
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, there's [a core issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2696555) to make the revision fields configurable.  Please help with that if possible, or use the [Hide Revision Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_revision_field) module if not.